# Add an updatemenu for dates in a timeseries bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I want to create time series bar chart with an `updatemenu()` for dates. I have created the menu but I do not know how to connect it with my plotly bar chart.

```
date<-c("2007-12-31","2008-01-01","2008-01-02")
t1<-c(2200,3455,3456)
t2<-c(2280,3457,3456)
kl<-data.frame(date,t1,t2)

p <- plot_ly(kl,x = kl$D, y = kl$y, type = 'bar', name = 'Real Estate Index 1', marker = list(color = 'rgb(49,130,189)'),
             xbins = list(
               end = "2008-01-02", 
               size = "M1", 
               start = "2007-12-31"
             )) %>%
  add_trace(kl,y = kl$z, name = 'Real Estate Index 2', marker = list(color = 'rgb(204,204,204)')) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "", tickangle = -45),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         margin = list(b = 100),
         barmode = 'group',
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             x = 0.1, 
             y = 1.15,
             active = 1, 
             showactive = TRUE,
             buttons = list(
               labels("D1", "Day"),
               labels("M1", "Month"),
               labels("M6", "Half Year"),
               labels("M12", "Year")
             )
           )
         ))
p
```